# Execute code once all "complete" functions have finished on list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that I animate to fade out.  After this has finished I want to run some code but want to run the code once, as opposed to every time each element in the list has finished animating.  The code must be run once ALL animation has finished and all `li`'s have been removed.  Here is my current code:

```
$(".myclass li").animate({'opacity':'0', 'height':'0%'}, function(){
    $(this).remove(); //This is run for every "li" which is fine...

    function() { /* I want to now run this code only once AFTER all animation has finished */ }
});
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at .one() : http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.queue() should help you with this. http://api.jquery.com/queue/

```
$(".myclass li").animate({'opacity':'0', 'height':'0%'},{"queue":true});
$(".myclass li:last-child").queue(function() {
    /* The code you want to run */
});
```

Comment: $(".myclass li").animate({'opacity':'0', 'height':'0%'});
$(".myclass li").queue(callback);

Comment: It really is the best solution to this issue. You don't have to count or anything. Just queue the animations and then queue the callback.

Comment: There is, I think, a slight issue with this - I remove each `li` meaning that `li:last-child` is invalid once the operation is complete... Whatever the cause it runs the code twice on first run and never runs after that... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be:

```
var elts=$$(".myclass li"),
    num=elts.length,
    onComplete=function() { 
        ...
    };

elts.animate({....}, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   if(--num === 0 && onComplete) {
       onComplete();
   }
});
```